# Using JavaFX How do I initialize a ComboBox to a specific selection?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am currently working on a project using JavaFX where I have 3 `ComboBox`es. One for selecting and displaying the hour, another one for the minutes and a third one for selecting AM or PM.

When a value in one of the `ComboBox`es is selected, it enters a timestamp into my `SQL-Database`. What I am trying to do now is have a selection shown when the window opens, in the initialize method, using an index with the goal of taking my Timestamp from the selection in the database and having the `ComboBox`es set with the time from the database.

I have tried:

```
StartCB.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
```

and

```
StartCB1.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

hoping the value will show when I open the window.

Any ideas? I have copied my code from the class below.
Thank you,
Jeff

```
/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author jdhinkle
 */
public class ModifyAppointmentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Customer> Customers;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> CustomerId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> CustomerName;
    @FXML
    private TextField Title;
    @FXML
    private TextField Description;
    @FXML
    private TextField Location;
    @FXML
    private TextField Contact;
    @FXML
    private TextField URL;
    @FXML
    private TextField Start;
    @FXML
    private TextField End;
    @FXML
    private Button Save;
    @FXML
    private Button Cancel;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker StartDate;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker EndDate;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox StartCB;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox StartCB1;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox StartCB2;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox EndCB;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox EndCB1;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox EndCB2;
    private Object customer;
    private Object appointment;

    private static Customer SelectedCustomerA;

    public static void SetSelectedCustomerA(Customer Selected) {
        SelectedCustomerA = Selected;
    }

    private static Appointments SelectedAppointment;

    public static void SetSelectedAppointment(Appointments Selected) {
        SelectedAppointment = Selected;
    }

    private static Login SelectedLogin;

    public static void SetSelectedAppointment(Login Selected) {
        SelectedLogin = Selected;
    }
    private LocalTime startD;
    
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        Title.setText(SelectedAppointment.getTitle());
        Description.setText(SelectedAppointment.getDescription());
        Location.setText(SelectedAppointment.getLocation());
        Contact.setText(LoginScreenController.getContact());
        URL.setText(SelectedAppointment.getURL());
        LocalDateTime startD = LocalDateTime.parse(SelectedAppointment.getStart().toString());
//        StartCB.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
//        StartCB1.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
//        StartCB2.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
//        if (startD.getHour() >= 12 ){
//            boolean hour(true);
//            hour = StartCB2.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
//        }
//        Start.setText(startD.toLocalTime().toString());
        StartDate.setValue(startD.toLocalDate());
        //End.setText(SelectedAppointment.getEnd());
        LocalDateTime endD = LocalDateTime.parse(SelectedAppointment.getEnd().toString());
//        End.setText(endD.toLocalTime().toString());
        EndDate.setValue(endD.toLocalDate());

        System.out.println(SelectedAppointment.getTitle());

        CustomerId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customerID"));
        CustomerName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customerName"));
        Customers.getItems().setAll(CustomerTab());
        Customers.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> SetSelectedCustomerA(newValue));
        Customers.getSelectionModel().select(indexCust());
        
        ObservableList<Integer> hours = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            hours.add(i);
        }
        StartCB.setItems(hours);
        EndCB.setItems(hours);
        //StartCB.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
        
        ObservableList<String> minutes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        minutes.add("00");
        minutes.add("15");
        minutes.add("30");
        minutes.add("45");
        StartCB1.setItems(minutes);
        EndCB1.setItems(minutes);
        
        ObservableList<String> ampm = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ampm.add("AM");
        ampm.add("PM");
        StartCB2.setItems(ampm);
        EndCB2.setItems(ampm);

    }
    
    public LocalTime STimeSet() {

        LocalTime StartTimeV = null;
        int n1 = (int) StartCB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (StartCB2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            n1 = n1 + 12;

        }
        int index = StartCB1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        int minutes = 0;
        switch (index) {
            case 0: minutes = 0; break;
            case 1: minutes = 15; break;
            case 2: minutes = 30; break;
            case 3: minutes = 45; break;
            default: minutes = 0;
        }
        StartTimeV = LocalTime.of(n1, minutes);
        return StartTimeV;

    }
    
    public LocalTime ETimeSet() {

        LocalTime EndTimeV = null;
        int n1 = (int) EndCB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (EndCB2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
            n1 = n1 + 12;

        }
        int index = EndCB1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        int minutes = 0;
        switch (index) {
            case 0: minutes = 0; break;
            case 1: minutes = 15; break;
            case 2: minutes = 30; break;
            case 3: minutes = 45; break;
            default: minutes = 0;
        }
        EndTimeV = LocalTime.of(n1, minutes);
        return EndTimeV;
    }
    
//    public LocalTime STimeCB() {
//        LocalTime StartTimeCB = SelectedAppointment.getStart();
//    }
    
//public LocalTime STimeSetCB () {
//    LocalTime StartTimeVCB = startD;
//}
    
    public int indexCust() {

        ObservableList<Customer> alist = CustomerTab();
        int index = -1;
        for (Customer c : alist) {
            //System.out.println(c.getCustomerID() + " " + SelectedAppointment.getCustomerID() );
            index++;
            if (c.getCustomerID().equals(SelectedAppointment.getCustomerID())) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Customer ID not found");

        return -1;
    }

    public ObservableList<Customer> CustomerTab() {
        SimpleStringProperty customerID = new SimpleStringProperty("ID");
        SimpleStringProperty customerName = new SimpleStringProperty("name");
        SimpleStringProperty active = new SimpleStringProperty("active");
        SimpleStringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty("address");
        SimpleStringProperty address2 = new SimpleStringProperty("address2");
        SimpleStringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty("city");
        SimpleStringProperty postalCode = new SimpleStringProperty("zipCode");
        SimpleStringProperty country = new SimpleStringProperty("country");
        SimpleStringProperty phone = new SimpleStringProperty("phone");

        ObservableList<Customer> customerTab = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT customer.customerId, customer.customerName, customer.active, address.address, address.address2, address.addressId, city.city, city.cityId, address.postalCode, country.country, country.countryId, address.phone FROM customer, address, city, country WHERE address.addressId = customer.addressId AND city.cityId = address.cityId AND city.countryId = country.countryId;");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
//            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
            while (rs.next()) {
                customerID = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("customer.customerId"));
                customerName = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("customer.customerName"));
                active = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("customer.active"));
                address = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("address.address"));
                address2 = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("address.address2"));
                city = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("city.city"));
                postalCode = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("address.postalCode"));
                country = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("country.country"));
                phone = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("address.phone"));
                SimpleStringProperty addressId = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("address.addressId"));
                SimpleStringProperty cityId = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("city.cityId"));
                SimpleStringProperty countryId = new SimpleStringProperty(rs.getString("country.countryId"));

                customerTab.add(new Customer(customerID, customerName, active, address, address2, addressId, city, cityId, postalCode, country, countryId, phone));
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqe) {
            System.out.println("Check your customer SQL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something besides the SQL went wrong.");
        }
        return customerTab;
    }

    @FXML
    private void SaveAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (Title.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || Description.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || Location.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || Contact.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || URL.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || Start.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                || End.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Empty Fields");
            alert.setHeaderText("Empty Fields");
            alert.setContentText("One or more fields are empty. Please fill out all fields");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }
        //Time from String --> LocalDateTime ---> ZonedDateTime(System Default) --Zoned SameInstance of (convert to UTC) ---> ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime ---> TimeStsmp
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement1 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.customerId = ? WHERE appointment.appointmentId = ?");
            statement1.setString(1, SelectedCustomerA.getCustomerID());
            statement1.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement1.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement2 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.title = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            statement2.setString(1, Title.getText());
            statement2.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement2.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement3 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.description = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            statement3.setString(1, Description.getText());
            statement3.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement3.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement4 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.location = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            statement4.setString(1, Location.getText());
            statement4.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement4.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement5 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.contact = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            statement5.setString(1, Contact.getText());
            statement5.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement5.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement6 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.url = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            statement6.setString(1, URL.getText());
            statement6.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement6.executeUpdate();

            //Time from String --> LocalDateTime ---> ZonedDateTime(System Default) --Zoned SameInstance of (convert to UTC) ---> ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime ---> TimeStsmp
            PreparedStatement statement7 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.start = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            LocalDate SDate = StartDate.getValue();
            //LocalTime STime = LocalTime.parse(Start.getText());
            LocalTime STime = STimeSet();
            LocalDateTime StartDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(SDate, STime);
            ZonedDateTime startT = StartDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            ZonedDateTime startTime = startT.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            //ZonedDateTime startTime = ZonedDateTime.of(StartDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            Timestamp startTS = Timestamp.valueOf(startTime.toLocalDateTime());
            statement7.setTimestamp(1, startTS);
            statement7.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement7.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement statement8 = DataBaseC.getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET appointment.start = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");
            LocalDate EDate = EndDate.getValue();
            //LocalTime ETime = LocalTime.parse(End.getText());
            LocalTime ETime = ETimeSet();
            LocalDateTime EndDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(EDate, ETime);
            ZonedDateTime endT = EndDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
            ZonedDateTime endTime = endT.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            //ZonedDateTime endTime = ZonedDateTime.of(EndDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            Timestamp endTS = Timestamp.valueOf(endTime.toLocalDateTime());
            statement7.setTimestamp(1, endTS);
            statement7.setString(2, SelectedAppointment.getAppointmentID());
            statement7.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");

        }
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Stage oldWindow = (Stage) Save.getScene().getWindow();
        oldWindow.close();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(ApptAppJeffHinkle.class.getResource("view/MainApp.fxml"));
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene2);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void CancelAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Stage oldWindow = (Stage) Save.getScene().getWindow();
        oldWindow.close();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(ApptAppJeffHinkle.class.getResource("view/MainApp.fxml"));
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene2);
        stage.show();
        //tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try any of those methods (or just [`setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setValue-T-)) *after* populating the combo box...

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I can set a value, or is there a way to set it using the Index of the values that are already populated in the ComboBox? When I try StartCB.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);, I have a message that setSelectedIndex(int) has protected access in the SelectionModel

Comment: Call `getSelectionModel().select(1)`

Comment: See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html#select-int-)

Comment: I figured it out using setValue(). I really appreciate your feedback